# Custom TableViewCell lose its own variable when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have the following Custom `TableViewCell`

[image: Custom TableViewCell]

The red(minus) and green(plus) button counts the left label "1"(in code snippet var myQuantity). If I scroll up and down in the tableView the variable myQuantity is always reset to 1 for selected cells.

I read that I have to set the myQuantity in the cellForRowAt method. But how can I set the cell value with its own class variable when its changed via green and red button?

Here my Custom Cell Class:

```
class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var quantityLabel: UILabel!
var myQuantity = 0

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    
    self.quantityLabel.text = String(self.myQuantity)
    self.leftLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.rightLabel.sizeToFit()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        self.myQuantity = 1
    } else {
        self.myQuantity = 0
    }

    self.quantityLabel.text = String(self.myQuantity)
}

@IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !self.isSelected { return }
    
    self.myQuantity += 1
    self.quantityLabel.text = String(self.myQuantity)
}

@IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !self.isSelected { return }
    if self.myQuantity == 1 { return }
    
    self.myQuantity -= 1
    self.quantityLabel.text = String(self.myQuantity)
}}
```

Here the `cellForRowAt` Method in my `ViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customArticleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleTableViewCell {
            let name: String! = categoryArticles[indexPath.row].name
            let price = categoryArticles[indexPath.row].price
            let price2f = String(format: "%.2f", price)
            
            cell.accessoryType = .none
            cell.leftLabel.text = name!
            cell.rightLabel.text = "\(price2f) €"
            
            if cell.isSelected {
                cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
            }
            
            return cell
       }

}
```

Comment: When one cell disappears it's added to queue and when next cell appears the view from queue is being reused. That's why you can't store data in cells, you should only store it on some upper level, e.g. view controller

Answer (score 0):

```
class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var leftLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var rightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var quantityLabel: UILabel!
    
    var addAction: (()->())?
    var minusAction: (()->())?
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.selectionStyle = .none
    }
    
    func setupCellWith(data: CategoryArticle) {
        self.accessoryType = (data.isSelected == true) ? .checkmark : .none
        self.leftLabel.text = data.name
        let price2f = String(format: "%.2f", data.price)
        self.rightLabel.text = "\(price2f) €"
    }
    
    @IBAction func addButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.addAction?()
    }
    
    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.minusAction?()
    }
}

struct CategoryArticle {
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    var isSelected: Bool?
    var quantity: Int?
}

let categoryArticles: [CategoryArticle] = []

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customArticleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleTableViewCell
    
    let categoryArticle = categoryArticles[indexPath.row]
    cell.setupCellWith(data: categoryArticle)
    
    cell.minusAction = { [weak self] in
        
        // Action you want to do like decrease the count in the model at indexPath.row and set selection in th model too and reload the tableView cell
    }
    
    cell.addAction = { [weak self] in
        
        // Action you want to do like increase the count in the model at indexPath.row and set selection in th model too and reload the tableView cell
    }
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).